# Where can I find out input command from EFI Shell?

Tags: efi

does anyone know where can I find out 'input' command in EFI shell?
And i tried two version of efi shell, one is v2.0 and another is v2.31, but these verion, I still find any of input command. So, I don't know how to get input command from efi shell?

So, need you help...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what is it you can't find? The command or its documentation?

Comment: Sorry, it's command of input. I wanna it be like ‘set /p var=please input a sting？‘

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for input command as well.

Although some websites list an input command for the efi-shell (e.g. https://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/5991-1247B/ch04s13.html) they don´t tell the efi version this list shall be valid for. And in shell version 2.1 I can´t find any input argument.

My workaround is to use python scripts. You can find the needed files to use python in efi shell at [https://github.com/chipsec/chipsec/tree/master/**install**/UEFI](https://github.com/chipsec/chipsec/tree/master/__install__/UEFI) or https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/AppPkg/Applications/Python